# SFDX CLI Permission Set Assignment Windows error

Tags: salesforcedx, permission-sets

I have a permission set "Platform_Admin" which I can assign from the org, but when I try to do an assignment through CLI with the following command

`sfdx force:user:permset:assign -n Platform_Admin` I get `Permission set "P" not found in target org. Do you need to push source?`. It's weird since this command works for me on Mac. Seems like it only takes the first character for some reason (I checked with different names and the message specifies the first character).

Have someone encountered a similar issue with this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue - https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/802

I have resolved this issue by running this command:

`sfdx plugins:install user`

It looks like they will resolve it in an upcoming release. The work around seems to work well though.

Comment: thanks, haven't haven't found it on GitHub